# Split the time period into multiple periods

Tags: ruby, date

I have a date range as follows

```
from = Date.parse('05.01.2017')
to   = Date.parse('10.03.2018')
```

I want to split the date range by 30 days as follows. I want to include the from and to date.

I found this reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39958476/how-to-divide-a-time-period-into-multiple-periods). But I don't find from and to date in the response. How can I do this?

Expected Output:

```
05.01.2017 - 03.02.2017
04.02.2017 - 05.03.2017
06.03.2017 - 04.04.2017
...
07.02.2018 - 10.03.2018
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @sawa I have updated my expected output

Comment: The expected output is still not completely clear, but I assume that you want an array of strings that would be printed as such. The output you have does not seem to be grouped by months in any way. Can you expand on that?

Comment: I want 30 days date range for every iteration. So that I can pass the 30 days date range as start and end date to api call to fetch reports.

Comment: That is not a month. It is 30 days range. And still, what you have shown is not grouped in 30 days. For example, take `05.01.2017 - 05.02.2017`. The number of days in that range is (31 - 4) + 5 = 32 != 30.

Comment: Ok. How can I split the date range by 30 days?

Comment: `05.01.2017 - 04.02.2017` in your expected output after the edit, is still not 30 days. It is 31 days.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188747/discussion-between-karan-and-sawa).

Comment: I have updated the expected output

Comment: `08.02.2018 - 10.03.2018` isn't 30 days.

Comment: Updated the date range

Comment: @karan check my answer, just updated on basis of your question update

Comment: @karen Range `07.02.2018 - 10.03.2018` should not appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require "date"

from = Date.parse('05.01.2017')
to   = Date.parse('10.03.2018')

first = from.jd
(from..to)
.chunk{|date| (date.jd - first) / 30}
.map{|_, (first, *, last)|
  "#{first.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")} - #{last.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")}"
}
```

Output:

```
05.01.2017 - 03.02.2017
04.02.2017 - 05.03.2017
06.03.2017 - 04.04.2017
05.04.2017 - 04.05.2017
05.05.2017 - 03.06.2017
04.06.2017 - 03.07.2017
04.07.2017 - 02.08.2017
03.08.2017 - 01.09.2017
02.09.2017 - 01.10.2017
02.10.2017 - 31.10.2017
01.11.2017 - 30.11.2017
01.12.2017 - 30.12.2017
31.12.2017 - 29.01.2018
30.01.2018 - 28.02.2018
01.03.2018 - 10.03.2018
```

Comment: What code needs to be changed if we use following from and to instead of Data.parse.  from = Time.find_zone(@time_zone).local(2018,11,01).beginning_of_day and
 to   = Time.find_zone(@time_zone).now.yesterday

Answer (score 1):

```
from = Date.parse('05.01.2017')
to   = Date.parse('10.03.2018')

s = from
e = s + 29
begin
  puts "#{s.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')} - #{e.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')}"
  s = e + 1
  e =  (s + 29 < to ) ? s + 29 : to
end while (s < to)
```

**Output:**

```
05.01.2017 - 03.02.2017 # 30 days
04.02.2017 - 05.03.2017 # 30 days
06.03.2017 - 04.04.2017 # 30 days
05.04.2017 - 04.05.2017 # 30 days
05.05.2017 - 03.06.2017 # 30 days
04.06.2017 - 03.07.2017 # 30 days
04.07.2017 - 02.08.2017 # 30 days
03.08.2017 - 01.09.2017 # 30 days
02.09.2017 - 01.10.2017 # 30 days
02.10.2017 - 31.10.2017 # 30 days
01.11.2017 - 30.11.2017 # 30 days
01.12.2017 - 30.12.2017 # 30 days
31.12.2017 - 29.01.2018 # 30 days
30.01.2018 - 28.02.2018 # 30 days
01.03.2018 - 10.03.2018 # remaining days till to (10.03.2018)
```

**NOTE:** `01.03.2018 - 10.03.2018` is not 30 days range. but as per OP's comment I have displayed date till `to`

Comment: I don't find date range upto 10.03.2018

Comment: Still it shows upto 11.02.2018 not a date range upt 10.03.2018

Comment: @karan updated answer, check output

Comment: I need exact date upto 10.03.2018. But still it shows upto 28.02.2018

Comment: @karan check the note, 01.03.2018 - 10.03.2018 is not 30 days range.

Comment: But I want to include that range even though it is not 30 days.

Comment: @karan : updated my answer

Comment: @karan "But I want to include that range even though it is not 30 days. "--You have not written so in the question. It is impossible to show the days in 30 days and finish on the `to` date at the same time.